# Error: Invalid character in name at (1) main.f95:249.1:

Tags: fortran

I am trying to compile a fortran file along with files in FORTRAN. The file  contain definition for common blocks of variable. When I compile them in Fortran, I get the following error:

> Error: Invalid character in name at (1) main.f95:249.1:

Now my question is, does this because of Fortran 77 style line continuations and I am trying to compile with Fortran 90? What is the solution?

The lines of code which this errors points is

```
  PACF(IT) = PACF(IT) + STORA(J1,I) * STORA(J2,I)
:                   + STORB(J1,I) * STORB(J2,I)
:                   + STORC(J1,I) * STORC(J2,I)
:                   + STORD(J1,I) * STORD(J2,I)
:                   + STORE(J1,I) * STORE(J2,I)
:                   + STORF(J1,I) * STORF(J2,I)
:                   + STORG(J1,I) * STORG(J2,I)
:                   + STORH(J1,I) * STORH(J2,I)
:                   + STORI(J1,I) * STORI(J2,I)
```

Answer (score 3):

The line continuation is different in free form then it is in fixed form. You lines should read:

```
  PACF(IT) = PACF(IT) + STORA(J1,I) * STORA(J2,I) &
                      + STORB(J1,I) * STORB(J2,I) &
                      + STORC(J1,I) * STORC(J2,I) &
                      + STORD(J1,I) * STORD(J2,I) &
                      + STORE(J1,I) * STORE(J2,I) &
                      + STORF(J1,I) * STORF(J2,I) &
                      + STORG(J1,I) * STORG(J2,I) &
                      + STORH(J1,I) * STORH(J2,I) &
                      + STORI(J1,I) * STORI(J2,I)
```

You can mix files of both forms for compilation, so the easiest solution would be to rename your file to `*.f`. 
BTW: Some compilers don't understand `*.f95` (and what would you do with Fortran 2003/08/15)? So it is kind of customary to use `*.f90` for free form Fortran and `*.f` for fixed-form.

Comment: it is working. Thanks a lot!